# How to dismiss the survey

Tags: bug, status-completed, survey

How can I get rid of the blue bar after I have completed the survey?

If I click the `x` button it disappears, but it comes back as soon as I reload the page or open a new tab. So it is not permanent:

---

[image]

---

I am using Google Chrome Version 78.0.3904.97 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan Ermine).

Comment: I thought we had these issues ironed out, but evidently not. Sorry about that. A few things are weird here - chief among them is that we don't have a history record in the DB that you were invited in the first place *and* I don't see any relevant exceptions. I probably won't have a chance to look into this until it auto-dismisses (that takes 3 days), but if you could give me some more information in the meantime, hopefully that'll help. When did this banner first appear for you? Are you blocking any cookies? If you click the X button, does a cookie called `ssb` get set and if so, what's in it?

Comment: @AdamLear I think the banner appeared today (or maybe yesterday). I am not blocking any cookies that I am aware of. If I search the cookies in chrome related to stackoverflow.com, I get 7 cookies but none of them is called `ssb`.

Comment: IIRC it wouldn't survive a page reload... so just to confirm, if you dismiss the banner, the cookie isn't set at that time either?

Comment: No it is not set as far as I can see. If I dismiss the banner one new cookie appeared in the list but it is not called `ssb`

Comment: What is it called?

Comment: I think it is called `_gat`, see [screen shot](https://imgur.com/a/QfBAkay)

Comment: Hmm. That's unfortunately unrelated to this feature. Interesting. Thanks for the info, I'll see what I can figure out.

Comment: I've removed the [status-review] tag from this post since it was closed as a duplicate of another one.

Comment: I've added the [status-completed] tag to this post since it was closed as a duplicate of one that had been completed. :-) If it's not completed, then a new bug report should be posted, or you can flag this one to have it reopened and retagged.